# Python Commands For a login Page

Tags: python, authentication, command

I need some help on how i would add more commands to this program to show a list of Films(or data) from a notebook or text file

```
def main():
command = username = password = ''
logged_in = False
while command != 'quit':
    command = input('Please type a command: ')
    if command == 'log in':
        logged_in, username, password = log_in()
    if command == 'log out':
        logged_in = False
        username = password = ''
    if command == 'new user':
        if not logged_in:
            new_user()
        else:
            print ('First logout to make a new user')
```

This Is the Full Code:

```
print("------------------Welcome------------------")
print("--Do you need to make a new user or login--")
def log_in():
username = input("Please enter your username : ")
password = input("Please enter your password : ")

with open('test_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line == 'Username:{0}, Password:{1}'.format(username, password):
            print ("Greetings," , username, "you are now logged in")
            return True, username, password
print (" Sorry username and password incorrect please re-enter for 
validation ")
return False, '', ''

def new_user():
succes = False
while not succes:
    new_user = input("Please enter your new username : ")
    new_pass = input("Please enter your new password : ")

    exists = False
    with open("test_file.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.split(',')[0] == 'Username:'+new_user:
                print ('Invalid username: {0} already 
exsist'.format(new_user))
                exists = True

    if not exists:
        with open("test_file.txt","a") as file:
            file.write('Username:{0}, Password:{1}'.format(new_user, 
new_pass))
            file.write("\n")
        succes = True
print ('You made a new user with username:{0} and password:
{1}'.format(new_user, new_pass))

def main():
command = username = password = ''
logged_in = False
while command != 'quit':
    command = input('Please type a command: ')
    if command == 'log in':
        logged_in, username, password = log_in()
    if command == 'log out':
        logged_in = False
        username = password = ''
    if command == 'new user':
        if not logged_in:
            new_user()
        else:
            print ('First logout to make a new user')

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is too broad. Please take a moment to look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please correct the indentation and errors in your code